# Laravel Eloquent How can I select and manipulate rows in pivot table?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have three database tables called user(id,name), group(id,name) and user_group(user_id, group_id,valid_before) with relations many to many.

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user';

    public function groups()
    {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class, 'user_group')
        ->withPivot('valid_before');
    } 
}

class Group extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'group';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_group');
    }
}
```

User can be member of some group until time moment 'valid_before'. If 'valid_before' is less than current time, the user must be excluded from the group and corresponding row in pivot table must be deleted. How can I select in pivot table rows where strtotime($validBefore) < strtotime($date)   and then delete them using Eloquent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use cronjob then simply use `detach($group_id)` like below:-

```
$user = User::find($id);
if(time_exceeded($user->id))  //checks if user should stay in a group
$user->groups()->detach($group_id);
```

use this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships) for refernce

Comment: Is this code suitable:                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                          
        $users = MyUser::all();
        foreach($users as $user) {
            foreach ($user->groups as $g) {
                $validBefore = $g->pivot->valid_before;
                if(strtotime($validBefore) < strtotime($date)) {
                    $user->groups()->detach($g);
                }
            }
        }